# Switch Statement Reverse

Tags: java, switch-statement

Okay so i'm trying to complete this project for school and it is asking me to make a switch statement of the months. So if a user enters 1 it will print out January and so on... I get this error where it says: cannot find symbol - variable January

```
import java.util.*;
/**
 * Outputs the number on a month name entered by the user.
 * 
 * @author Jack
 * @version 1a
 */
public class MonthSwitchReverse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

        int monthString;
        String month;



        System.out.println(" Jan = 1 / Feb = 2 / March = 3 / April = 4 / MAy = 5 / June = 6");
        System.out.println(" July = 7 / Aug = 8 / Sep = 9 / Oct = 10 / Nov = 11 / Dec = 12");
        System.out.print("Choose a month above and the system will print out the number assigned to that month: ");
        month = in.next();


        switch (month) {
            case "January":  monthString = 1;
                     break;
            case "February":  monthString = 2;
                     break;
            case "March":  monthString = 3;
                     break;
            case "April":  monthString = 4;
                     break;
            case "May":  monthString = 5;
                     break;
            case "June":  monthString = 6;
                     break;
            case "July":  monthString = 7;
                     break;
            case "August":  monthString = 8;
                     break;
            case "September":  monthString = 9;
                     break;
            case "October": monthString = 10;
                     break;
            case "November": monthString = 11;
                     break;
            case "December": monthString = 12;
                     break;
            default: monthString = 404;
                     break;
        }
        System.out.println(monthString);
    }
}
```

EDIT: I fixed it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well where do you *think* you've defined those symbols? (And if the idea is for the user to input the *name*, why are you using an `int` for the user input?)

Comment: I also don't know where `January` is defined. Do you mean `"January"`? or do you mean "a variable called `January`"?.

Comment: Can I ask why this question is downvoted? Ok, its an easy mistake, but  a valid question, with reproduced code - we can see what they have attempted.

Comment: Your class description says "Outputs the number on a month name entered by the user". But you're reading ints? Your other mistake has already been stated, the symbols of your switch statement are undefined.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are passing an integer to switch , That each case should be an int value.

For example

```
  case 1:  monthString = "1";
  case 2:  monthString = "2";
```

And same for remaining all.

recommending to read : [`Switch in java.`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)